# Why is south migrate failing?

Tags: django, django-south

I have a blank MySQL database that I've just created. `south` is in my `INSTALLED_APPS`.

I run:

```
$ ./manage.py syncdb
...
Creating table some_app_table

You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
...
Superuser created successfully.
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

Synced:
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
...

Not synced (use migrations):
 - myapp
...
```

```
$ ./manage.py schemamigration myapp --initial
 + Added model myapp.Model
...
Created 0003_initial.py. You can now apply this migration with: ./manage.py migrate myapp
```

```
$ ./manage.py migrate myapp
Running migrations for myapp:
 - Migrating forwards to 0003_initial.
 > skan:0001_initial
 > skan:0002_initial
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: CREATE TABLE `myapp_model` (`id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, `user_id` integer NULL, `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL);
The error was: (1050, "Table 'myapp_model' already exists")
```

What's going on? Why won't South initialise correctly?

Comment: `--initial` should only be used to create the initial tables; you've already created a table `myapp_model`.

Comment: If possible recreate the database and run the --initial migration again without running syncdb

Comment: @Wooble The tables don't exist before I run the command, I double checked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have some migrations defined: `initial` is (as expected) only needed for the initial migration.

Your `syncdb` output says:

```
Not synced (use migrations):
 - myapp
```

Which indicates that south is working as expected. But, then you do:

```
$ ./manage.py schemamigration myapp --initial
+ Added model myapp.Model
...
Created 0003_initial.py. You can now apply this migration with: ./manage.py migrate myapp
```

Notice the `0003`-prefix: this (most likely) indicates that there are already migrations defined. This is confirmed by the output of your next command:

```
$ ./manage.py migrate myapp
Running migrations for myapp:
 - Migrating forwards to 0003_initial.
 > skan:0001_initial
 > skan:0002_initial
 <snip>
```

In other words, you already have a couple of `initial` migrations, of which at least one will create that table. Your #3 migration tries this again, but fails, because the table of course exists by now.

What you need to do is only use `initial` on the creation of your Django app. As soon as the `migrations` folder contains a file called `0001_initial.py`, you don't need any initial migrations anymore. If you change your table from this point on, call it with `auto`, and then migrate:

```
./manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto
./manage.py migrate myapp
```